# _mysql_plugin_interface_version_ error when installing plugin under Windows

Tags: mysql, c, plugins, mingw, visual-studio-express

I want to compile AUDIT_NULL plugin using Visual Studio Express. I have compiled it on windows with mingw like

```
$>gcc -Iinclude -fPIC -share d -o plugin_example.dll plugin\audit_null\audit_null.c  -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN
```

successfully.

But I have no idea where to put option MYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN in VSE2013. I put it in `Properties | Configuration | C++ | Additional Parameters` like `/DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN=` and `/DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN` and `MYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN=` and `MYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN`, and to `Command Line` like `/DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN=` and in some other places but have no effect. I also tried to put definition just into source code but it didn't help.